# How to aggregate a dataframe by rowname

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
    Names   Thing1  Thing2  Thing3  Thing4  Thing5

     Seb1        10       5      10       5      10
    John1         1       2       3       4       5
     Seb1        10       5      10       5      10
    John1         1       2       3       4       5
     Sue3         7       7       7       7       7
```

I would like to aggregate on the basis of the rowname

I tried this

```
 df<-aggregate(.~(df$Names),data=df, FUN = sum,na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL
```

but I got the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind() ~ rownames(total2), data = list( : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'cbind()'
```

Comment: Do you have a column `row.names`?   It seems that you have a matrix.

Comment: Are they actual row names and a `data.frame`? Or a variable named `row.names`? Duplicate row names are generally not allowed in `data.frame`s (though they are in matrices). Please use `dput(head(yourdf))` or create a reproducible sample.

Comment: The column is not called row.names. They are the row names. This is a dataframe

Comment: If this is a `data.frame` , these are **NOT** row names by definition.

Comment: Ah. Yes you're right. It is a dataframe but these arent rownames

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion. Your comment under @koundy's answer indicates that you are working with a matrix.

Comment: It would have been easier to show the `str` or `dput` as AnandaMahto suggested rather than guessing back and forth.

Comment: Apologies. I cant do dput as the info is sensitive. Once I did df<-as.data.frame(df) I could then run the aggregate function and it worked fine. I will edit the question so that its a data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to group by rownames and sum all columns? try this

```
 library(dplyr)
    df %>% group_by(row.names) %>% summarise_each(sum)
```

Comment: This gives me the error Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: your object seems to be a matrix. try converting it to dataframe `df <- as.data.frame(df)`

Comment: Yes that worked koundy. And then I used total2<-aggregate(.~rownames(total2),data=total2, FUN = sum,na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)

Answer (score 3):

`data.frame` cannot have `duplicate` row names.  If you don't have a column named 'row.names', then it must be a matrix.  One option would be to use `rowsum` which can work both on matrix and data.frame.

```
rowsum(m1, row.names(m1))
```

For the new dataset

```
rowsum(df1[-1], df1$Names)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), Names]
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(10L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 
10L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 7L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Seb1", "John1", "Seb1", "John1", "Sue3"
), c("Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3", "Thing4", "Thing5")))

df1 <- structure(list(Names = c("Seb1", "John1", "Seb1", "John1", 
"Sue3"
), Thing1 = c(10L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 7L), Thing2 = c(5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
7L), Thing3 = c(10L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 7L), Thing4 = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 7L), Thing5 = c(10L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 7L)), .Names = c("Names", 
"Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3", "Thing4", "Thing5"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Btw, this would work no matter if this is a matrix or a `data.frame`. `rowsum` is generic and have methods for both.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it would.  I was pretty sure that the OP didn't have a data.frame as the row.names were duplicates.